# How to stop xcode git from picking up other git projects?

Tags: xcode, git

I've just started using xcode.

I went to commit my test project, and on the directory tree on the left hand side of the commit window, it showed not only my test project but also another git project in a completely different directory to my ios project.

It may have picked it up when I copied some resources from that other project to my test project or something, but I can't figure out how to unlink it.

Why is it picking up my other project?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have one git-controlled folder inside another (unrelated) git-controlled folder?

Comment: @matt Thanks - it's a good thought, but the unwanted project doesn't seem to be nested inside my ios project. It's somewhere completely different in my filesystem. Xcode source control seems to have decided that I want it to control that git project too, but I don't, and I can't see where to tell it to stop trying to manage it. Thanks!